# var React = require("react"); Почему не работает?

Tags: reactjs

Бьюсь над проблемой уже третий день, перерыл весь интернет на русском и на английском (как смог). Ответа не нашёл. Прошу вашей помощи.

Суть проблемы: установил через npm React и ReactDOM. В `node_modules` они добавились. Подключаю. Не видит. Пишет в консоли "React is undefined". А если подключаю через cdn, то все работает.

Что в коде:

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

var Note = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div>Me</div>
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Note />,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Comment: Подключаете где? Какие инструменты вы используете чтобы делать require в клиентском коде? browserify? webpack? requirejs?

Comment: 1. Подключаю в .jsx файле. Проблем с компиляцией jsx в js не возникло.
2. Для сборки проекта использую Gulp.js. В нем require работает как положено(кроме как с Реактом). Ни browserify ни webpack ни requirejs не использую.
Если мой вопрос очень прост и ответ вам очевиден, то прошу помочь. Я на самом деле не пойму почему не работает.

Comment: Покажите, как ваш файл выглядит в браузере.

Comment: Ссылка на изображение: http://skrinshoter.ru/s/171116/FI5gRX?a

Comment: Это не в браузере.

Comment: Мы хотим видеть скомпилированный код, чтобы чтобы понять во что превращаются ваши require после обработки галпом

Comment: Если я верно понял что требуется показать: http://skrinshoter.ru/s/171116/i0dONX?a

Comment: если честно, я криминала с ходу не вижу. Подозреваю что проблема может быть в том как галп видит пути для node_modules. Возможно, помогут конфиги галпа. Вообще какие-нибудь npm модули нормально реквайрятся?

Comment: В общем. Разобраться не удалось. Сделал как предлагают на официальном сайте: npm install -g create-react-app. Они используют Webpack. В качестве решения был сделан выбор разработку SPA делать на нем, а не на Gulp.js. Спасибо всем вам что не оставили и помогали своими советами.

Comment: `А если подключаю через cdn, то все работает.` - я так подозреваю, что `index.html` просто не получал файл с библиотекой Реакт. Поэтому и `React is not defined`.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно вы используете ECMAScript6. Попробуйте вместо:

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
```

Написать

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Comment: ДА папка е него react названно на скринне видно

Answer (score 1):

СreateClass это устаревший способ объявления компонентов. В вашем случае объявить компонент можно так

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Note extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
    Hello!
  )
 }
}
```

Чтобы создать структуру проекта на Реакт рекомендую воспользоваться модулем create-react-app, очень удобная штука.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример реализации стандартного компонента в React.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1 className="h1">Hello world!</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App'; // Указываете путь до компонента App

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root')); // 1) Указываем какой компонент будет стартовым 2) Контейнер
```

Answer (score 0):

еще проблема "React is undefined" возникает тогда, когда библиотека установлена, но не добавлена в package.json

проверьте в этом файле "dependencies:"

если нет, то устанавливайте модули командой:

```
npm i react --save
```

Answer (score 0):

еще так можно

```
import * as React from 'react';
```